# What happens to getopts when the end of options is encountered

Tags: bash, getopts

Bash manual says

> ```
> getopts optstring name [args]
> ```
>
> When the end of options is encountered, `getopts` exits with a return
>   value greater than zero. `OPTIND` is set to the index of the first
>   non-option argument and `name` is set to `?`.

In an example from [the Bash Hackers Wiki `getopts` tutorial](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial):

```
while getopts ":a" opt; do
  case $opt in
    a)
      echo "-a was triggered!" >&2
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      ;;
  esac
done
```

When the end of options is encountered, `getopts` exits with a return
value greater than zero, so the while loop will stop. Then inside the while loop, is    the part inside  `\?)` never reached? If yes, why is it there?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s there to process invalid options. In the example, if you run `script -a`, the `-a` option is expected and results in “`-a` was triggered!”. If you run `script -b`, `-b` isn’t valid and will be handled by the `\?` case, resulting in “Invalid option: `-b`”.